# Propogate input field from react app to mongodb database

Tags: node.js, database, reactjs, mongodb, express

Got 80% there. Just need help connecting the front end to the back end. Have done research but still couldnt understand it.

I created my node express backend, as well as my React client. I also have created my mongodb acoount and placed the mongoURI into the configs/api/keys.js file. Also have created my schema in the item.js file. I just need to know how where else I need to write code to connect the react to mongo. Thank you!

To simplify the process, here is my repository https://github.com/kenny335/shoppingList

I want to connect to the backend. Please let me know

Comment: Are you getting any errors ? Can you change main to server.js instead of index.js in package.json

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the api using [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) or [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch). the on response update the ui of the app.

eg:

```
//to get data
axios.get("apiEndpoint")
      .then(({ data }) => {
        this.setState({data});
      })

//then based on this data in state change the ui
```